# Ms Access : Math Functions with a report

Tags: ms-access

I have a report in access which displays the number of times a certain procedure is a done as well as a break down of the scores received, which can either be "N" "B" or "C"

I want to include in my report the % of procedures that are deemed below standard. These are the scores and of N and B combined.

I have written the following to work this out

```
=([B]+[N])/[Total Of Entry ID]*100
```

The problem occurs if either N or B do not have a value which is possible then it does not calculate the percentage. Is there a way I can tell it that if there is no value to assume the value is zero?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Nz()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx) function to apply a substitute if the field is null;

```
=(Nz([B], 0) + Nz([N], 0))/ ...
```